# Unable to work CocoaPods

Tags: cocoapods

I'm doing an online Objective-C course and i've hit the following problem:
I seem to have installed CocoaPods via the Terminal.

When I went to install CocoaPods this text displayed in the terminal: "Successfully installed cocoapods-0.39.0 Parsing documentation for cocoapods-0.39.0 1 gem installed"

I then continued by following the example:

1) I entered: pod 'SAMGradientView' into 'podfile' in Xcode.

2) Reopened the Terminal.

3) I then entered "cd" into the Terminal, then dragged the Example Xcode Project file to the Terminal. I then pressed enter and nothing happened.

Comment: Your question is not about iOS or Objective-C. Please use the correct tags.

Answer (score 1):

After editing the podfile, you need to install the pod by issuing the command "pod install" in the terminal.

Detailed instructions to install an cocoapod and integrating with xcode project is provided in this [link](https://guides.cocoapods.org/using/using-cocoapods.html).

Answer (score 0):

plz follow these steps to install cocoa-pods to your project.

```
//if cocoa-pods is not installed in your system else skip first step

Step 1.$ sudo gem install cocoapods

Step 2.change directory to xcode project in terminal

Step 3.$ pod init

Step 4.$ open -a Xcode Podfile

Step 5.insert your pod library( pod 'SAMGradientView') into opened pod file and save this file.

Step 7. $pod install (if pod installation first time in your project)

or $pod update (to update existing pods)
```